# Watson Conversation: condition matching input to context array

Tags: watson-conversation

Taking the car dashboard example, I altered the initial @genre node to be @genre:classical.  I also added a list to the contex

```
"choices":["Beethoven","Mahler 9","Brahms 3rd"]
```

and the Watson response is `"I have 3 selections"`. The condition on the next node is `$choices.contains(input.text)`. The "Found a match" response is just for testing.  It looks like this:

[image]

When I test this in the api tool and type "Beethoven" both "Found a match" and "Great choice!..." appear. Same for the other two choices, but only if I type the *exact* choice, e.g., "Mahler 9".  Typing "Mahler" or "mahler" doesn't get a match.  I read through the SpEL documentation but couldn't see a way in a one-line condition to parse through the list looking for partial matches.

So my question is, is there an condition expression that would match partial user input, e.g., "Mahler"?  I'll be using the Java SDK to code the app server, so alternatively I wondered if I could add a temporary @entity just for this sequence instead of using the context list then delete it when the conversation is done? Or is there a way to construct a more complex condition in the MessageRequest and will Watson recognize it? Or is this just not the right way to go about this?  Any pointers, examples or docs much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is, is there an condition expression that would match partial user input

You can't add temporary entities or intents. As adding them forces Watson to start training itself (even if you could it through code).

You can however create quite complex regular expressions, pass them in as a context variable.

For example your advanced node can have:

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": "Please ask me a question."
  },
  "context": {
    "rx": "fish|[0-9]+"
  }
}
```

Then in you condition you would write.

```
input.text.matches(context.rx)
```

This will then trigger if the person mentions a number, or the word fish. So you can create your partial user input checking that way.

Comment: Thanks, Simon.  I didn't think you could add entities or intents but thought I'd mention it anyway.  Regex is not one of my strengths but your example gives me enough clues to try out some solutions.

Comment: Just tried it out and this should definitely work!  Thanks again.

Comment: Simon, FYI. I spent the last couple of weeks working on a POC and then integrating it into my website, along with STT and TTS.  It worked fine for those terms that have intents and entities but I struggled with the two nodes that have the condition you suggested.  Aside from the fact that STT regularly returns garbage (different issue) it turned out that the the STT result included a space at the end of the word or phrase.  Obviously that didn't match the regex phrase. Once I finally figured that out (hours later) and trimmed the input text for the MessageRequest I got the correct response.